# Preface and Table of Contents Issue

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, arabic, roman

I am in the final stage of writing my dissertation and it seems like there are some issues with how my preface's contents are being displayed on the table of content. The dedication page should start from page number iv. I see the dedication on page iv, but on the table of content, it shows up as "****chapterDedicationivsection*.1***". The other preface sections(starting from page v)show up as expected on the table of content. Can anyone please provide me any suggestions? The code and a screenshot are attached for the reference.

[image: code]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Never use screenshots to post code, because it prevents people from copy-pasting your code to test it. Also, read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to provide compilable LaTeX code. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code of a small complete sample code (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows, when compiled, the problem you are observing. To answer your question, we need to know the documentclass, the packages loaded etc. `preface` and `\prefacesection` are no standard commands, so we cannot give advice without knowing their definition.

Comment: Where/How is the `preface` environment defined? That could well be your problem but you haven't given us any useful information.